# ES6 google maps api CORS probelm or NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError

Tags: google-maps, es6-modules

I am trying to work with google maps on ES6.

If i do :

```
import "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key"
```

I get a CORS error.

If I download the source code requesting https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key > save as local_googlemaps.js . I am able to import with

```
import "../../thirdparty/js/google_maps.js"
```

But when try to load the map with location info, I got "NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError", related with the source Code is not loaded from api.googleapis.com.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with manual import :

```
          const script = document.createElement('script');
          script.src = `//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${apiKEY}`;
          script.async = true;
          document.body.append(script);
```

But, any other suggestion?